# display carousel caption below carousel images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

how to display carousel caption below carousel images in max-width 767px?

**html:**

```
<div class="item active">
    <img src="img/3.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4><a href="#">news</a></h4>
        <p></p>
        <a class="label label-success" href="#" target="_blank">readmore</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #myCarousel.carousel-caption{
    }
}
```

Comment: We need css code to see the behavior at >767px

Comment: it would be nice if you show your issue in an more detailed example, 
maybe on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0px;
 
 text-align:right;
 padding:2px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       vertical-align:bottom;

Comment: @media(max-width:767px){left:0; right:0; bottom:0px; text-align:right; padding:2px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); vertical-align:bottom;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's enough to use jquery codes below:
'#myCarousel' is id of your carousel

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
      $("#myCarousel .item img").next().removeClass('carousel-caption').addClass('caption');     
       } 
        else {
        $("#myCarousel .item img").next().removeClass('caption').addClass('carousel-caption');
      }
   });
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Just remove the `class="carousel-caption"`

```
<div class="item active">
    <img src="img/3.jpg">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4><a href="#">news</a></h4>
        <p></p>
        <a class="label label-success" href="#" target="_blank">readmore</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `carousel-caption` i used `text-center` for center alignment

Comment: No ,I want to my text was shown below image in media screen 767px.but in large screen text was inside image

Comment: 767px which means ? sm size or md size ?